# sum of values from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql, select, sum

I have 3 tables:

```
table A: building_id, region_code
table B: building_id, storey_no
table C: building_id, storey_no, room_no
```

What query would calculate sum of room numbers for all the buildings in each region with number of storeys in certain range (below is the sample query which doesn't work as I don't know how to include table B in it with the condition on number of storeys, etc.)?

```
SELECT SUM(C.room_no) AS room_sum, A.building_id 
FROM A,B,C
WHERE A.region_code=1 
AND A.building_id=C.building_id 
AND B.storey_no>3
AND B.storey_no<10
GROUP BY C.building_id,C.room_no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining on building_id from all three tables as below:

```
SELECT SUM(C.room_no) AS room_sum, C.building_id
FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.building_id = B.building_id
INNER JOIN C
ON A.building_id = C.building_id
WHERE A.region_code=1
AND B.storey_no>3
AND B.storey_no<10
GROUP BY C.building_id
```

Comment: This query doesn't work as it doesn't sum up numbers of rooms in the buildings, but instead shows the same building several times with different room numbers on each storey.